# Fill multiselect dropdown depending on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select dropdown list and a multiselect dropdown. And i want the multiselect one to be depended on the select one. How can i do it?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col" ><label>Which class: </label><select name="type_of_subject_c" id="type_of_subject_c" tabindex="1">
<option value="" selected="selected">--не выбрано--</option>
<option value="5">5th </option>
<option value="6">6th</option>
<option value="7">7th</option>
<option value="8">8th</option>
</select>
</div>
```

And i want, for example, if a person chose 5th - show in the multiselect field such options as "Math", "English", "Literature"
If a person chose 6th - show "Math", "Science", "Music"
etc.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col"><label>Coruses: </label><select   name="course_subj_c[]" id="course_subj_c" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1" >
<option value="math">Math</option>
<option value="eng>English</option>
<option value="lit">Literature</option>
```

Comment: Do you have any code? Have you tried anything?

Comment: i tried to do it via arrtibute "rel" but it didn't work for multiple.

Comment: Alright, but if you want our help, you should always put your code so we can see your efforts. Remember StackOverflow is a place to learn. I've answered your question, see below working example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't achieve this just using HTML. 
You need to use JavaScript in order to populate the other dropdown with elements depending on the value chose in the first dropdown.
Add an `onchange` event to the first dropdown. 
Inside this function, clear all the option elements of the second dropdown. Then depending on the selected value of the first dropdown, fill the second one. Here an example of code using jQuery.

```
    <select name="first-dropdown" id="first-dropdown" onchange="processValue();">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Default Option</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>

    <select name="second-dropdown" multiple="multiple" id="second-dropdown">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Select option in the first dropdown</option>
    </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function processValue() {
        var firstChoice = $('#first-dropdown').val();
        // ensure you didn't select the default option
        if (firstChoice !== "") {
            $('#second-dropdown').empty();
            switch (firstChoice) {
                case "1":
                    $('#second-dropdown').append('<option value="first1">First 1</option>');
                    $('#second-dropdown').append('<option value="first2">First 2</option>');
                    break;
                case "2":
                   $('#second-dropdown').append('<option value="second1">Second 1</option>');
                   $('#second-dropdown').append('<option value="second2">Second 2</option>');
                   break;
                // ... other cases
                default:
                   break;
            }
            // init jquery checkbox plugin again
            $('#second-dropdown').multipleSelect();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here the link to jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/37swkpso/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't worked for me.. The multiple field isn't filled with options :(

Comment: processValue function seems to be not linked in the HTML.
Add the code inside a `<script></script>` tag and be sure the tag is below the selects.
I assumed that as implicit, btw changed the code above including the script example as well

Comment: can you paste me a link to the new working code in jsfiddle please?

Comment: Here my example working:
https://jsfiddle.net/37swkpso/

I just implemented the first two choices of the first dropdown, so just them are working...
It's the same code of the beginning

Comment: Here the example working:
https://jsfiddle.net/37swkpso/

You have a syntax error in your code. When using jsfiddle, keep your console open, it will show you errors. 
Then your code is not linked correctly inside jsfiddle. 
You have to click in top right corner of the javascript panel, select nowrap in body and remove the script tags inside the javascript code, I meant to add them inside your HTML example. 
Again, take a look to my example in jsfiddle and select one of the first two options, you should see the second dropdown populated

Comment: it worked in jsfiddle but it doesn't in the browser... i don't know what's wrong

Comment: copy my code above that is in the answer inside your page, it should work fine wrapping it inside script tag

Comment: well i got the problem. earlier i added jquery plugin that makes checkboxes in multiselect dropdown...and when i delete this plugin and its script your code is working...but i need checkboxes too, how can i combine jquery plugin and your code?

Comment: can you paste me the link to the jquery plugin you are using?

Comment: is the plugin not working only in the second dropdown right? the one generated dynamically?

Comment: changed the code above in the answer in order to integrate that plugin, let me know if it works please because I've never used that plugin

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should always add code to your question even if it is not working. Stackoverflow is a place to learn, how can we help you if you don't share your work.

---

Array `data` contains all your data. We add `options` to both `select`s dynamically.

Function `init()` is where it starts. To change the data we need to add an event listener to our second select like so

```
select1.addEventListener('change', function(e) ...
```

Here is working example. Please read my comments to have better understanding. If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask.

```js
var data = [
  { subject : 'one', 
    selected: true,
    courses: ['Math_one', 'English_one', 'Literature_one'] 
  },
  { subject : 'two',
    courses: ['Math_two', 'English_two', 'Literature_two'] 
  }, 
  { subject : 'three',
    courses: ['Math_three', 'English_three', 'Literature_three'] 
  },
  { subject : 'four',
    courses: ['Math_four', 'English_four', 'Literature_four'] 
  },
  { subject : 'five',
    courses: ['Math_five', 'English_five', 'Literature_five'] 
  },
  { subject : 'six',
    courses: ['Math_six', 'English_five', 'Literature_six'] 
  }
];

var select1 = document.getElementById('type_of_subject_c');
var select2 = document.getElementById('course_subj_c');
var resultText = document.getElementById('currentlySelected');

// Your result, do whatever you want
var selectedOptions = [];

function init(data) {

  var subjects = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var element = data[i];
    
    // Add subjects to subjects array
    subjects.push(element.subject);
    
    
    // We skip if current element is not selected
    if (!element.selected) {
      continue;
    }
    
    // If element is selected we change content of `select2`
    if (element.selected) {
      fillSelectOptions(select2, element.courses);
    }
  }
  
  // Append all subjects as select options to `select1`
  fillSelectOptions(select1, subjects);
  
}

// Lets add event listener `onChange` to `select`
select1.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  // Based on selected/current value we will change data options of `select2`
  var selectedValue = e.target.value;
  
  // Clear result text each time we change `select1`
  resultText.innerHTML = '';
  selectedOptions = [];
  
  // Before we append new data lets clear old one
  clearSelect2Options();
  
  // Lets find related data to selected/current value
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var element = data[i];
    
    if (element.subject === selectedValue) {
      fillSelectOptions(select2, element.courses);
      
      break;
    }
  }

});

select2.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var options = document.querySelectorAll('#course_subj_c option');
  
  resultText.innerHTML = '';
  selectedOptions = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var option = options[i];
    if (option.selected) {
      selectedOptions.push(option.value);
    }
  } 
  
  
  // Our Result is :
  //console.log(selectedOptions);
  // Append result to `resultText` convert array to string via `join()`
  resultText.innerHTML = selectedOptions.join();

});



function fillSelectOptions(selector, dataOptions) {

  for(var i = 0; i < dataOptions.length; i++) {
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.innerHTML = dataOptions[i];
      opt.value = dataOptions[i];
      selector.appendChild(opt);
  }
  
}

function clearSelect2Options() {
    var i;
    for(i = select2.options.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        select2.remove(i);
    }
}

init(data);
```

```html
favorite
 


<select id="type_of_subject_c" name="type_of_subject_c">
</select>

<select name="course_subj_c[]" id="course_subj_c" multiple="multiple" tabindex="1">
</select>

<div>Currently selected <span id="currentlySelected"></span></div>
```

Comment: Lots of thanks for your answer. But, you know, i need values of options to be saved..

Comment: You did not mention that in your question.  I've updated my answer. Should be working now, see working example. To access selected data use `selectedOptions` array. Mark my answer as `answered` if it helped you.